# Copy a formatted value in SlickGrid

Tags: angularjs, slickgrid

I have created a slick grid with some formatted values. Column values were formatted by writing a custom formatter.  But when I copy and paste a cell I am getting original value. How can I copy the formatted value from the SlickGrid

Comment: Do you work with dataview?

Comment: Yes It's data view